# Find element position array in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, position

I need to write some methods for a game in java and one of them is int[] findStone. The method returns an array, which gives the coordinate of the element that I am searching.

[The field looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIkK2.png) and is defined like this: `private static int[][] gamefield = new int[8][6];`
So if I use the method: findStone(3)[0], it should return 0 for the x coordinate and for findStone(3)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIkK2.png), 2. This is the code that I wrote.

```
private static int[] findStone(int stone) {

        int[] position = new int[2];

        for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++ ){
            for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++ ) {

                int a = gamefield[x][y];
                int i = x;
                int j = y;

                if(a == stone) {
                    position[0] = i;
                    position[1] = j;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;

    }
```

The problem is: The method only returns the x-coordinates for the first row corectly, for the other elements it shows me 0. Could someone explain me what I did wrong and what I should change? Please, only simple explanation. I am only at the beginning and I don't have experience in java.
Thank you :)

Comment: because you use break for y loop, it just run single time.

Comment: Can you clear up what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Besides `break` in the wrong place, you should also break out of both loops at the same time or your code keeps going for the remaining x values (which is at least a waste of cpu cycles): see [break with label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) (2nd half of that page) or consider to `return position` immediately instead of breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably intended to put your `break` clause inside the `if` block. The way you have it now, the `break` keyword has no effect. It just breaks the inner loop (with `y` variable), but since this block of code ends here anyway, it simply does nothing.

You're searching for a single point on your map, so when you find the stone position, you can immediately return it, as there's nothing more to do.

Moreover, you don't need additional variables, `a`, `i` and `j`. Using them is not wrong, but code looks clearer and is more concise without them. Have a look at this code:

```
private static int[] findStone(int stone) {

    int[] position = new int[2];

    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {

            if (gamefield[x][y] == stone) {
                position[0] = x;
                position[1] = y;

                return position;
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // if there's no given stone
}
```

Comment: Good luck with writing your game!